# What should I install to make my Firebase system recognize class="btn btn-action hide" ? (I assume it's a custom built CSS class?)

Tags: css, firebase

So the code below didn't work because the class="btn btn-action hide" is not recognized by the system because it is a custom built class by Firestore rather than a default built-in class in CSS. If that is the case, what should I install to make it work because I've already tried installing everything from Firebase and it still does not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Firebase Web Quickstart</title>


<script 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">

<input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">

<button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-action">
  Log in
</button>

<button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-secondary">
  Sign Up
</button>

<button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action hide">
  Log out

</button>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have no idea what you are talking about, not working because it's not hiding? Firebase is realtime database, CSS is...CSS, if you don't have the .hide css class, it won't hide.

Comment: Mindless: it's not working because "btn btn-action hide" is not recognized because it's a custom built class from Firebase. What should I install or what should I do to get that custom built class "btn btn-action hide" in my system so that it will get recognized? I've tried installing everything I could find regarding Firebase and it's still not working.

Comment: Show me where you downloaded the code so I can have a look, you are just missing sass or the css file

Comment: the code I wrote in my question was not downloaded. It was shown on a youtube tutorial and I wrote it into my Visual Studio Code.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU

Comment: You are missing the sass or the css file, I can't help without knowing how/where you copied the code, don't worry i got the link thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the youtube example you've shown, it does not show you the css file. But I think it's using bootstrap from identifying the class name, here is what you can try:

Copy-paste the stylesheet link into your head before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Firebase Web Quickstart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
```

Please do note this is CDN, you can also download bootstrap yourself and add the file from your local path.

Update, the youtube video is using custom css that looks like bootstrap but it's not...to use bootstrap classes for button, see below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Firebase Web Quickstart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">

<input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">

<button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-primary">
  Log in
</button>

<button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-secondary">
  Sign Up
</button>

<button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-danger" hidden>
  Log out

</button>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the classes you can use:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

[image]

Comment: I did that and the button still didn't hide. Maybe I should download bootstrap myself.

Comment: If you want to hide the button, try <button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action" hide></button>, I think it's just simply missing the hide class.

Comment: or add the class yourself <style>.hide{display:none}</style>

Comment: oops my bad hidden should be the word <button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action" hidden></button>

Comment: Still didn't work... and also the coloring and fancy appearance on those buttons didn't appear either...(but it did on the youtube tutorial) which means it's not just 'hide'... but basically all the button CSS is not appearing because it's not recognized...

Answer (score 0):

just use the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged will get similar purpose with out using bootstrapcdn  but at first have to get document element id like below:

```
const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
const btnLogout = document.getElementById('btnLogout');


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if (firebaseUser) {
        console.log(firebaseUser);
        btnSignUp.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
        btnLogout.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```